# Javascript inside jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I know how to use javascript inside jsx. i am doing it like so:

```
            {this.state.players.map(function(player, index) {
              index +=1;
              return <div key={index}><span>{index}. {player.name}</span><span>{player.rank}</span></div>
            })}
```

but why cant i add another method like this:

```
this.state.players.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (a.rank) - (b.rank);
});
```

anywhere?

i have tried appending it to the function, before, after. and it just says invalid syntax `{` pointing to opening and closing brackets. i want to sort my array and then map over it essentially.

Comment: Show the invalid code.

Answer (score 1):

In JSX brackets you should insert valid JSX tag or array of tags or statement that returns one of them. In the first example `.map` returns array of `div`s. This is why it is valid.

In this case you can chain array methods.

```
this.state.players.sort(function(a, b) { return (a.rank) - (b.rank); }).map(/*...code*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pro tip:
You can execute any JavaScript code you want in curly brackets. Just use IIFE:

```
{
  (() => {

    const sorted = this.state.players.slice().sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.rank - b.rank;
    });

    const divs = sorted.map(function(player, index) {
      index += 1;
      return (
        <div key={index}>
          <span>
            {index}. {player.name}
          </span>
          <span>{player.rank}</span>
        </div>
      );
    });

    return divs;
  })()
}
```

even better idea is to prepare elements beforehand.